# Handling high number of concurrent GSM device connections

Tags: switching, mobile

How do telcos manage high concurrent GSM dial ins or dial outs? We are deploying thousands of remote, GSM enabled utility meters and have to manage too many GSM modems that the meters will dial in to. What is the better way of handling this?

Comment: Removed off-topic request for product/resource recommendations.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: We are still evaluating a few solutions at the moment. For the sake of accuracy I will only accept solution that will solve major parts of the problem

Comment: That's fine. We are simply trying to clean things up, and people sometimes forget. If you come up with a solution, please post an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard BTS (with 3 cells) can handle around 9 erlangs which is enough to support circa 1500 subscribers, but everything depends. All station are built to suit terrain and people density on given area. Is very difficult to say as you have not specified if those modems are 3G, GRPS or LTE. 
For example LTE with 2x20Mhz wide, 4x4Mimo and 64QAM could reach as much as Download ~300Mbps and ~80Mbps uplink. Not all modems have active connction all the time. Some connected send data some are in RRC-Idle. As well if there is mutliple devices they would share channel/bandwitch (stat-mux).

Edit:
So you are using modems as gateway for each meter to dial in? 
I'm pretty suprised as this solution is not scalable. I would say that much better would be to access destination servers over IP from GSM provider network, rather than dial-in into dedicated gateways.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot go with the GSM provider network route as our calculation indicates that the recurring cost is going to to be untenable with regards to our profitability. We are rolling out our own telco infra for our utility meters network.

Comment: Most of the modems are 3G and GPRS. The meters are to dial in and report the measured electricity usage for the premise.